# Get class from Template in a method in C#

Tags: c#, templates, generics

I need to pass `GridViewCommandEventArgs` or `GridViewRowEventArgs` or `int` in a Generic method and want to get the values out of it.

Example code:

```
public struct RemarkStruct
{
    public string remarkId;

    public RemarkStruct(string _remarkId)
    {
        remarkId = _remarkId;
    }
}

public RemarkStruct GetRemarkData<T>(T val)
{

    if (val is GridViewCommandEventArgs )
    {
        GridViewCommandEventArgs gvCommandArgs = (GridViewCommandEventArgs) val;

        int rowIndex = GetRowIndex_CommandEvent((T) val);
        //
        GridViewRow row = ((GridViewRow)(((ImageButton)gvCommandArgs.CommandSource).NamingContainer));
        remarkId = (row.FindControl("imgBtnDelete") as ImageButton).CommandArgument;

        RemarkStruct remStruct = new RemarkStruct(remarkId);
        return remStruct;
    }
}
```

And I want to call from the below method.

```
protected void gvRemark_RowCommand (object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GetRemarkData<GridViewCommandEventArgs >(e);
}
```

I have just written the code for `GridViewCommandEventArgs` similarly I want to write for `GridViewRowEventArgs` and for int also.

Comment: I think you should re-think your generic approach as a generic one usually means you may use ANY type not only three or four. Otherwise you´d have to take care on many different checks of validation. You may create an interface which all of your three different implementations implement, thus it´s more clear what your method actual does.

Comment: @HimBromBeere thanks. Actually I need to use more number of types but  right now I have mentioned 3 of them in order to make my question as small as possible. I am definitely noob in these things. So please bear with me. I might be a bit irritating but at the end I want to learn things. Can you have any example of what you said. Sorry to take your time and thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Interface, something like this...

```
using System;

public struct RemarkStruct
{

}

public interface IEventArgs
{
    RemarkStruct GetRemarkData();
}

public class GridViewCommandEventArgs : EventArgs, IEventArgs
{
    public RemarkStruct GetRemarkData()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class GridViewRowEventArgs : EventArgs, IEventArgs
{
    public RemarkStruct GetRemarkData()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and your method will look like this...

```
protected void gvRemark_RowCommand (object sender, IEventArgs e)
{
    e.GetRemarkData();
}
```

I don't know if this is the most elegant way but you can override this method to get int as argument

```
protected void gvRemark_RowCommand (object sender, int e)
{
    //... 
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I love to learn and you helped me a lot.

I have a doubt please if you can answer. Can we use these events as class?? Because these are the events of GridView of asp.net. Sorry for the noob doubt.

Comment: The events can't be used as class.But EventArgs is a class and GridViewRowEventArgs and GridViewCommandEventArgs should inherit EventArgs too. I edited my post. Hope this works

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am very much thankful to you. Please clear one more doubt (very noob) possibly. Can protected void gvRemark_RowCommand (object sender, IEventArgs e) method can be fired instead of protected void gvRemark_RowCommand (object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e). I feel I'm irritating others but I want to work with this approach as I feel these kind of learning improves my interests. Please bear with me again.

Comment: In the EventHandler you will point this method gvRemark_RowCommand so this method will be fired and in the place of IEventArgs you can put any class that implement IEventArgs and this case EventArgs. I hope this is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

if have created generic than than you can pass other type also in generic function..you can check type of T and than write your code according to it.

Example :

```
public RemarkStruct GetRemarkData<T>(T val)
{
 if (typeof(T) == typeof(MyClass))
 {
    MyClass mc = (MyClass)(object) t;
 }
 else if (typeof(T) == typeof(List<MyClass>))
 {
    List<MyClass> lmc = (List<MyClass>)(object) t;
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. You saved my day. I have one more question. Please can you let me know how to restrict to perticular types of generics. Like I just want to restrict him to GridViewCommandEventArgs, GridViewRowEventArgs and int.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @MuhammedAli - for restricting type you can check generic constrain : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx in your case it might be partial helpful as you want to allow int also for other two type you can define constrain easily...and as int is value type you need another method with constain